# How to get Raspberry Pi CPU temperature in C++

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, temperature

I would like to know if there is a way to get the raspberry pi's CPU temperature in C++ code, I'm using a Raspberry Pi 4b.

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: read /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp like you would read any file on disk.

Comment: Divide by `1000` for Deg C. (integer division is fine, or you can using floating-point if you care about the decimal place)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this, ....
...

```
td::string fileName = "/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp";
std::ifstream piCpuTempFile;
float piCpuTemp = 0.0;
std::stringstream buffer;
piCpuTempFile.open(fileName);
buffer << piCpuTempFile.rdbuf();
piCpuTempFile.close();
piCpuTemp = std::stof(buffer.str()); // convert string to float
piCpuTemp = piCpuTemp / 1000; // convert float value to degree
piCpuTemp = roundf(piCpuTemp * 100) / 100; // round decimal to nearest      
std::cout << "CPU Temperature: " << piCpuTemp << "°C\n";
```

...

Comment: Why so much extra code just to read from a file? There's no need for the `std::stringstream` at all, just read directly into a `std::string`(or even directly to a `float`)